# Localization of e-mail templates in Tapestry 5?

Tags: localization, tapestry, email-templates

Tapestry provides a great localization support for their pages and components.
I would like to send localized e-mail corresponding to the users language preference.

Anybody has come across a solution for localizing e-mail templates that integrates well with Tapestry?
(I don't mind if it is a not using Tapestry's templating engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a separate directory/package for each language and retrieve the template file. And then used `ThreadLocale..getLocale().getLanguage()` to retrieve the current user's so I can send the e-mail on that language too.
Here is the relevant code snippet:

```java
public class MailSender {
    private static final String EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ROOT = "com/xxx/emailtemplate/";

    @Inject
    private ThreadLocale locale;

    public void sendEmail(..., final String emailTemplateFileName) {
        String emailTemplateFilePath = getEmailTemplateFilePath(emailTemplateFileName);
        ....
    }

    private String getEmailTemplateFilePath(String templateLocation) {
        String language = locale.getLocale().getLanguage();

        return EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ROOT + language + "/" + templateLocation;
    }
}
```

This is not specific to a templating engine. You can use this technique with your favourite. (I kept Velocity as it was used by the project already)